# Printing TRUE for dates less than today?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, compare

This is regarding date comparisons.
I'm unable to work out a query which returns TRUE for all rows where the date is before today's date.

I have a query which returns TRUE if today's date matches a row value from a column containing those dates, though.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (
SELECT WFD_AttText5, WFD_AttText1
    FROM WFElements
    WHERE WFD_DTYPEID = 83
    )
    THEN 'TRUE'
    ELSE 'FALSE'
END AS 'Match'
FROM WFElements
WHERE WFD_DTYPEID = 83 AND WFD_AttText5 IN
(        
    SELECT
        FORMAT (
        GETDATE(), 'dddd, dd.MM.yy', 'de-de')
    FROM WFElements
)
```

This returns TRUE for the one date which matches today's date. But how to I return TRUE for all rows less than today?
I think my problem is that I have to use IN() and cannot use < at the same time.

**EDIT: This query works better but is not always correct in printing TRUE:**

```
SELECT
    WFD_AttText5
AS 'Datum Formularfeld',
    FORMAT
(
    GETDATE
(), 'dddd, dd.MM.yy', 'de-de') AS 'TODAY formattiert',
    'TRUE' AS [Match]
FROM WFElements
WHERE
    WFD_DTYPEID = 83
    AND WFD_AttText5 < FORMAT
(
        GETDATE
(), 'dddd, dd.MM.yy', 'de-de')
```

This gives correct results (German) such as:

*Mittwoch, 25.05.22 | Freitag, 28.10.22 | TRUE*
meaning: Mittwoch, 25.05.22 < Freitag, 28.10.22 which is true.

But also wrong ones:

*Freitag, 30.12.22 | Freitag, 28.10.22 | TRUE*
meaning: It's supposed to be true, that Freitag, 30.12.22 is less than Freitag, 28.10.22 which is not true.

I'm almost there I hope.

Comment: Start by not treating dates as a string but as a date, then it is trivial. I *hope* your database doesn't have the fatal flaw that they are stored as strings.

Comment: based on the column name containing the word Text I'd assume the worst. Still, if the date from WFElements can be converted to string (and work all the time) then surely the string in WFD_AttText5 can be convert to date

Comment: No database in prod here, all good but thx for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return 'TRUE' for every row where WFD_AttText5 (assuming this is a str date with format dd.mm.yy) is less than the current day. For others it will return 'FALSE'.

```
SELECT
    WFD_AttText5,
    CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(DATE,WFD_AttText5,4) < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) THEN 'TRUE' -- 4 stands for dd.mm.yy format
        ELSE 'FALSE'
    END AS [Match]
FROM WFElements
WHERE WFD_DTYPEID = 83
```

Or like that if you only want 'TRUE' values :

```
SELECT
    WFD_AttText5,
    'TRUE' AS [Match]
FROM WFElements
WHERE
    WFD_DTYPEID = 83
    AND CONVERT(DATE,WFD_AttText5,4) < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

Other tips :
in `EXISTS` always use a `SELECT 1`

Your first query can be re-write as

```
SELECT 
    'TRUE' AS [Match]
FROM WFElements
WHERE
    WFD_DTYPEID = 83
    AND CONVERT(DATE,WFD_AttText5,4) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks, trying out but getting "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" for "CONVERT(DATE,WFD_AttText5,4)". WFD_AttText is a string with an equivalent date format of 'dddd, dd.MM.yy', 'de-de'. So I guess I cannot use pre-defined date formats (4).

Comment: try replacing your `CONVERT(DATE,WFD_AttText5,4)` by `CONVERT(DATE,TRY_PARSE(WFD_AttText5 AS DATE USING 'de-de'),101)`

Comment: Awesome, that worked! For me to understand: Is TRY_PARSE able to convert the string date 'Freitag, 30.12.22' to a date format that can be compared to CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) ?

Comment: `TRY_PARSE` set the result to null if it can't parse the string to date. By specifying `USING 'de-de'`, `TRY_PARSE` is able to convert 'Freitag, 30.12.22' to a date in US format. By default `CONVERT` and `GETDATE()` are in US format, so it is now possible to compare your two dates. It would be nice to specify US format in the last two fonctions to avoid server config problems

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider setting your topic to resolve.